# Telnet command windows to Linux server

Tags: linux, windows, telnet

telnet from a windows PC to a Linux server and view the users that are logged on the telnet server?what command do you use to view users logged on....commands i found don't work

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't be using `telnet` anymore but rather use `ssh` for more secure remote logins.

> What command do you use to view which users are logged on? The commands I found don't work

I don't know what you found and tried, but you can use `man -k <keyword>`  and/or `apropos <keyword>` to search a system database for available commands and their short description. That will list matching man pages, the section of the manual (see `man man` for a description of the sections) and the description.

To find suitable commands to find logged on users try

```
man -k "logged on" 
w                    (1)  - Show who is logged on and what they are doing
who                  (1)  - show who is logged on
```

or similar

```
apropos "logged in"
last                 (1)  - show listing of last logged in users
lastb [last]         (1)  - show listing of last logged in users
users                (1)  - print the user names of users currently logged in to the current host
```

which are all different user commands that give slightly different views on the users who are currently logged on or who logged on in the past (or who failed to do so in case of `lastb`). The manual pages i.e. `man w` or `man 1 w` will explain how to use those commands.